# Unnecessary Bootstrap Hover Class Being Added For No Reason?

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I am trying to create an extremely simple navbar. I have added bootstrap to my project as well as my own style sheet. I have included only 1 bootstrap class on my page (I think). I have added a custom hover effect but for some reason, I get the hover animation plus another animation playing with the color changing and other stuff.

Here is how the hover is right now:

[No Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDvFE.jpg)

[Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT2CO.jpg)

I want the text to stay white on hover and not have the black underline.

Here is my code:

**HTML/EJS**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Madhose</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
   <nav>
                <a href="#" class="logo">Madhose</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Poems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#recipes">Recipes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/posts">Posts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

<h1>Posts</h1>
<p><%= postText %></p>
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
  <h1><%= post.title.substring(0,200) %></h1>
  <p><%= post.content.substring(0,200) %>...
  <a href="/posts/ <%= post.title %>">Read More</a></p>
<%});  %>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');
.container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.navbar {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.footer-padding {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer p {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 120, 255);
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

li a {
    color: rgb(235, 222, 222);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: block;
}

li a::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: rgb(235, 222, 222);
    transition: width .3s;
}

li a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
    
}

.logo {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    display: flex;
    z-index: 3;
}
.logo:hover{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Oswald';
}
```

Im almost 100% sure this problem is happening from bootstrap but if its anything else please tell me!

Comment: `nav` is most likely used in bootstrap for a menu navigation and unless you are using a custom build, Bootstrap does apply a default theme. Your options are: overwrite their styles with your own CSS, get a stripped down themeless version of Bootstrap (you are using an older version which I believe still has this option) or scrap Bootstrap and use a barebones Framework that focuses on the core elements but doesn't apply styling.

Comment: @imvain2 I thought my nav bar styling was overwriting bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styling will only override bootstraps if you have your cascading correctly written.  If you use a tool like devtools in chrome and inspect the CSS of an element, you can see that there are multiple levels of CSS targeting an element, but not all are actively applied, as some are overwritten. Your styles may not take precedence if their cascading value does not come out to equal more than Bootstrap's value.

As such, if you want to override the values more consistently, use psuedo-namesapacing:

```
nav#topNavigation ul li a {}
nav#topNavigation ul li a:hover {}
```

By adding a unique ID to the element, we are increasing the cascade value for this selector, and our css is applied rather than Bootstrap's.

Comment: Worked! Thanks!!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped :)